# JavaParser: get field name from FieldDeclaration

Tags: java, javaparser

I've built up a list of FieldDeclarations and need to find out what the name of each field is:

```
List<FieldDeclaration> fields = classDeclaration.getFields();

for (FieldDeclaration field : fields)
{
    String fieldName = field.get...?
}
```

I can't find any methods that retrieve the name of the field.

Strangely though, one of the constructors does accept a field argument so not sure why it doesn't have a getter. Do I need to get it from another node?

> FieldDeclaration(NodeList modifiers, Type type, String name)
>   Creates a FieldDeclaration.
>   https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core/3.15.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor you mentioned is declared as this way

```
public FieldDeclaration(NodeList<Modifier> modifiers, Type type, String name) {
    this(assertNotNull(modifiers), new VariableDeclarator(type, assertNotNull(name)));
}
```

In the source code of `FieldDeclaration`, there is a nodelist of `VariableDeclarator`s as follows;

```
@NonEmptyProperty
private NodeList<VariableDeclarator> variables;
```

And you can get this private list with following method;

```
public NodeList<VariableDeclarator> getVariables() {
    return variables;
}
```

Once you get your list, you should use `VariableDeclarator` class methods, if you look at it's source code this method should work;

```
@Generated("com.github.javaparser.generator.core.node.PropertyGenerator")
public SimpleName getName() {
    return name;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can access source codes [here](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core/src/main/java/com/github/javaparser/ast/body/FieldDeclaration.java)